Upgrading to Ubuntu 24.10 (and clean install) breaks the system
I've upgraded Ubuntu from 24.04 to 24.10 on my Raspberry Pi 5 and during boot, the system crushes and enters to sort of panic mode, even when I burn a clean install via Raspberry Pi Imager…
Is it a known issue? what can I do?

Did you review the release notes? Query the bug tracker?
